# javascript string to date using custom format

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string `10/11/2012` meaning November 10, 2012.

But when I do `new Date("10/11/2012")` it returns October 11th.

How do I pass in the date format I want?  In this case `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: You can't. You could extend the native javascript date parser so it becomes possible though.

Comment: A little bit of a tangent, but the topic is how to handle locale when dealing with Date objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356839/javascript-date-object-in-different-locale-and-timezone   Remember, date objects represent a date in time, but that time is represented as a different hour of day depending on where you are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(format, Date) at this site:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/$.datepicker.parseDate

So I will be using the jQuery datepicker instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no JavaScript Date constructor that allows you to pass in culture information so that it uses localized date formats. Your best bet is to use the constructor that takes the year, month, and day separately:

```
var parts = dateString.split('/');
var date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10), 
                    parseInt(parts[1], 10), 
                    parseInt(parts[0], 10));
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `parseInt` be needed? Does the `Date` constructor accept strings?

Comment: Yes, it would need parseInt. Added.

Comment: @jdwire  it can deal with both

Comment: there is a implicit conversion : '5'==5 //true

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, you can use:

```
var dateparts = date.split("/");
var datestring = dateparts[1] + "/" + dateparts[0] + "/" +  dateparts[2];
var date = new Date(datestring);
```

In the more general case, you can extend the Date prototype, as demonstrated in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163314/1726343