# JavaScript Print Formatting

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I'm learning NodeJS and rewriting some code to see how it compares.  For one script, I am trying to take dates in the form of strings and turn them into JavaScript Date objects to perform calculations on.

I managed to do this, by converting the string into an array and processing each character.  It looks so ugly though, I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way, like the equivalent to sprintf or something.  I'm sure I can find a module but am wondering if there is a native way in JS.  This is what I have:

```
var a = '081320141900'.split('');
creationDate = a[0] + a[1] + "/" + a[2] + a[3] + "/" + a[4] + a[5] + a[6] + a[7] + " " + a[8] + a[9] + ":" + a[10] + a[11];
console.log('Creation Date: ' + creationDate);
```

Output:

```
Creation Date: 08/13/2014 19:00
```

Again, the above works fine, just wondering if this can be done cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would be using [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), but here, you can't, since your input date uses custom format.

But there are a few things you can improve:

- Use `new Date()` to build a date object. You can then format it.
- Use `parseInt()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13315097/240613)) on the substrings (e.g. `a.substr(0, 2)`).
- Validate your inputs.
- Use better names for your variables. `a` is not a good name.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  That bit was a snippet that I modified to ask the question, so I won't actually use 'a' in the actual program.  I do then pass the formatted string into a Date object and use that to calculate times. It looks like parseInt() and what you linked will help a lot.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to make it look a bit better.

```
#!/bin/env node
var dateString = '081320141900'.split('');
dateString.splice(2, 0, '/');
dateString.splice(5, 0, '/');
dateString.splice(10, 0, ' ');
dateString.splice(13, 0, ':');
createDate = new Date(dateString.join(''));
console.log(createDate);
```

That outputs:

```
Wed Aug 13 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

And lets me move forward with the calculations.  I'll add some code to catch if the Date object cannot be formed, etc. but at least this is a bit more legible.  Thanks all again for the help.